# How to make a Battleships game using Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, artificial-intelligence, swi-prolog

- In a game of battleships two opponents place minesweepers (2) and battle cruisers(2) on a grid. A minesweeper occupies two adjacent vertical or horizontal squares. A battle cruiser takes up three adjacent vertical or horizontal squares (no diagonal placings).
- The game progresses with each player guessing a row, column reference and the opponent indicating whether that is a hit or a miss.
- Construct a representation for the game of battleships and a set of rules that will govern actions for the human player and the computer player. The computer must report if the players grid reference is a ‘hit’ or a ‘miss’ as well as indicating whether or not the hit is a minesweeper or a battleship. As must the human when it is the computers turn.
- The computer must display its own board state to the human player with ‘x’ for a hit , an ‘m’ for a miss and ‘-‘ for unexplored squares, whenever the human player selects a cell.
- To place pieces on the board the human specifies the following **place**(**minesweeper,2,2,’west’**) which places minesweeper on two adjacent squares facing west starting from position 2,2 if it valid to do so and is asked to place all pieces declared in the game.
- The computer places it’s pieces randomly on valid squares around the grid.
- The computer cannot see the humans placement of pieces and must guess a square from the list of unexplored squares. The computer should have a clearly defined strategy if it happens to hit an item.

Here's a draft on building the board. Can anyone help figure out the rest from above?

```
% If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
% then enter the text in that file's own buffer.

count_to_list(0,[]).
count_to_list(N,[N|T]) :-
    NewN is N -1,
    count_to_list(NewN,T).
% test to see if a modulus is 0 for a count
maxCol(3).

test :-
    count_to_list(5,List),
    max_list(List,Max),
    Value is Max mod 5,!,
    Value == 0,
    format('~w~n',[Value]).

% place([m,m,b,b],StartBoard,FinalBoard).

testPlace(N,FinalBoard) :-
    retractall(maxCol(N)),
    assert(maxCol(N)),
    create_list_board(N,Board),
    place([m,m,b,b],Board,FinalBoard),
    printBoard(FinalBoard).


place([],FinalBoard,FinalBoard).
place([Symbol|T],Board,FinalBoard) :-
    maxCol(N),
    random_between(1,N,R),
    random_between(1,N,C),
    place(Symbol,R,C,Board,NewBoard),
    place(T,NewBoard,FinalBoard).

place(Pieces,Board,FinalBoard) :-
    place(Pieces,Board,FinalBoard).

place(Symbol,R,C,List,ResultingList) :-
    select([R,C,e],List,[R,C,Symbol],ResultingList).

:- dynamic maxCol/1.

create_test(N,R,C,B2,A,S) :-
    retractall(maxCol(_)),
    assert(maxCol(N)),
    create_list_board(N,Board),
    place(m,1,2,Board,B1),
    place(b,4,5,B1,B2),
    printBoard(B2),
    action(A,R,C,B2,S).


create_list_board(N,Board) :-
    create_rows(N,N,RBoard),
    reverse(RBoard,Board).
create_rows(0,_,[]).
create_rows(R,C,FinalBoard) :-
    NextRow is R -1,
    create_rows(NextRow,C,FinalRow),
    create_cols(NextRow,C,RowCols),
    append(RowCols,FinalRow,FinalBoard).
create_cols(_,0,[]).
create_cols(R,C,[[R,C,e]|FinalCol]) :-
    NextCol is C -1,
    create_cols(R,NextCol,FinalCol).

pieces([m,b]).

action(hit,R,C,Board,Symbol) :-
    pieces(List),
    member(Symbol,List),
    member([R,C,Symbol],Board),!.
action(miss,R,C,Board,_Symbol) :-
    member([R,C,e],Board),!.


% Last element in the grid representation
printBoard([[R,C,Value]]) :-
        interpret([R,C,Value] ,PrintValue),
    write(PrintValue), nl.

% last Column in the current row
printBoard([ [R,C,V] | Rest]) :-
    maxCol(C),
        interpret([R,C,V] ,PrintValue),
    write(PrintValue), nl,
    printBoard(Rest).

printBoard([ [R,C,V] | Rest]) :-
    interpret([R,C,V] ,PrintValue),
        write(PrintValue),
    printBoard(Rest).
:- dynamic hit/1, miss/1.

% hit([1,2,m]).
% hit([4,5,b]).
% miss([2,2,x]).
% then we could use rules return a revealed square
interpret([R,C,H],H) :- hit([R,C,H]) , !.
interpret(Square,x) :- miss(Square) , !.
% Or an unrevealed square
interpret(_,'-').


action_test(A,R,C,Symbol) :-
    action(A,R,C,[
                 [1,1,e],[1,2,m],[1,3,e],
                 [2,1,e],[2,2,x],[2,3,e]
    ],Symbol).

print_test :-
    printBoard([
                 [1,1,e],[1,2,m],[1,3,e],
                 [2,1,e],[2,2,x],[2,3,e]
    ]).

board_rows([
                 [ [1,1,e],[1,2,m],[1,3,e] ],
                 [ [2,1,e],[2,2,x],[2,3,e] ]
    ]).

test_board_row(NewBoard):-
    board_rows(B),
    place_in_row(b,2,1,B,NewBoard).

place_in_row(S,R,C,Board,OutBoard) :-
    nth1(R,Board,Row),
    select([R,C,e],Row,[R,C,S],NewRow),
    select(Row,Board,NewRow,OutBoard).

print_rows([]).
print_rows([Row|Rest]) :-
    printBoard(Row),
    print_rows(Rest).

test_print_rows :-
    board_rows(B),
    print_rows(B).
```

Comment: Did you write this code yourself?

Comment: @TA_intern No, it's from a college class on AI.

Comment: This is the starting point you got along with instructions how to proceed?

Comment: @TA_intern I don't know what else to add.

Comment: You want someone here to tell you how to write code for your AI class?